# Removing spaces, hyphen and brackets from a string

Tags: javascript, string, node.js

I am getting a string like:

```
 var str = '+91 1234567891,(432)123234,123-123-13456,(432)(567)(1234)';
```

I want to remove the spaces, hyphen and brackets from every number. Something like:

```
var str = '+911234567891,432123234,12312313456,4325671234';
```

Please suggest a way to achieve this.

Comment: See here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This will do your job:

```
var str = '+91 1234567891,(432)123234,123-123-13456,(432)(567)(1234)';

var result = str.replace(/[- )(]/g,'');

alert(result);
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) those items by empty string:

```
'+91 1234567891,(432)123234,123-123-13456,(432)(567)(1234)'.replace(/[\s()-]+/gi, '');
// results in "+911234567891,432123234,12312313456,4325671234"
```

Hope it helps.